# Why android resizes image?

Tags: android, resources, imageview

I'm trying to change my application data source to the sdcard so that it doesn't take too much internal memory.

However, I had an Image that was dynamically loaded from the resource and displayed in an ImageView, now I load the image from the sdcard whenever I need it.

I had been using `imageBox.setImageResource(imageID)` and I changed to `imageBox.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable)`.

The problem is that now Android resizes my image and it doesn't fit where it should.
Why is it resizing the image this way? And how can I stop it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think I found my problem. My ImageView is being resized using the intrinsic height and width. What does this mean? How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the tag `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your ImageView's layout XML.

Ex.

```
<ImageView
 ... several settings ...
 android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Edit:

If your image is simply too big to fit inside the ImageView - it will have to do some kind of scaling. There are some other options as described in the API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: My problem is quite the opposite. I'm trying to make no scaling t all. The problem is that if I load from the resources the image doesn't scale and fits as it should, if I load from the sdcard it gets resized to a smaller image and doesn't fill what it should... I tried change the scaling method but is makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for ImageView:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

No Scale Type.

The ImageView Should be within Fixed Size (in dp) Parent View.